# Android set Pie Chart color gradient

Tags: android, xml, view, gradient, pie-chart

I'm using MPChart library to create pie chart view, but i can't use gradient color for PieChart view (gradient works only with LineCharts).

I need to create pie chart view with gradient color like this:

[image: pie chart gradient]

Can anyone suggest me another library for android to create this view ?

Comment: check https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-pie-chart-using-mpandroidchart-library-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, but pie chart view in this tutorial does not apply gradient color.